# MongoDB: Update field with size of embedded array

Tags: mongodb

I have a `collection` of documents with an `array` (`set` in this case): `my_array`

I'm adding things to this `set` periodically

```js
collection.find({ "_id": target_id })
.upsert().update({ '$addToSet':{ 'my_array': new_entry }})
```

Many of the logical operations I perform on this DB are based on this sub-array's size.  So I've created a field (indexed) called `len_of_array`.  The index is quite critical to my use case.

In the case where this is a true `array` and not a `set`, the `$incr` would work beautifully in the same `update`

However, since the sub-collection is a `set`, the length of the collection, `my_array`, may or may not have changed.

**My current solution:**

Call this periodically for each `target_id`, but this requires performing a find in order to get the correct `len_of_array`

```js
collection.find({ '_id': target_id})
.upsert().update({ '$set':{ 'len_of_array': new_length }})
```

**My Question**
Is there a way to set a field of a document to the indexed size of a sub-array in the *same* document in a single update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the field `length_of_array` in order to query by its size. There is the [$size operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/). Which would save you the periodical update, too.

Let's say you want to find all documents for which the length of `my_array` is greater than 2:

```js
db.coll.find({ "my_array":{ "$size" :{ "$gt": 2 }}})
```

Comment: Thanks.  Am I correct in assuming that there is no way to index `$size`  I will update my question to explain that the field `len_of_array` is also indexed.

Comment: @puj Simply index the array.

Comment: Is this correct? My recent experience suggests that indexing an array (e.g. putting an index on a "doc.arr" field) does not allow for __indexed__ count, but rather the count will scan the document. Whereas searching for arrays that contain the value "x" __will__ use the index.

Comment: @mils Curious. Will check that. I think I had checked it when I wrote the answer, but I am not too sure.